# How to send an email to a webpage

Tags: email, html

I'm looking for any tools, or services, that allow me to send email to a website.  For example, if I have a form on a webpage, I can fill in the information and submit it.  What I'd like to do is put the information in an email and send that to the webpage, for the same processing.  Currently, what I *can* do, is using something like Twilio... where I can SMS the information and load it into a webpage... it's just fairly expensive.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

source here bro. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp you can send it to your email using this script..

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, I'm looking to send an email TO my website, not send one FROM it.